# reference an input attribute affect rendering result

Tags: c++, glsl, opengl-3

I see very weird behavior:
Vertex shader:

```
in vec2 vTextCoord;
in vec3 vPosition; //model coordinates
out vec2 texCoord_;
void main()
{
    texCoord_ = vTextCoord;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
in vec2 texCoord_;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 fColor;

void main() 
{ 
    fColor = vec4(texCoord_.x,1,1,1); //when using this line I get image 1
    //fColor = vec4(1,1,1,1); // when using this line I get image 2
}
```

These shaders do nothing, and they are not called. Images are generated by other shaders.
The only interaction these shaders has with opengl, is that I compile and link them into a program.

Still:
When using (in the fragment shader) the line: 
    fColor = vec4(texCoord_.x,1,1,1);

I get the following buggy rendering:
[image: Image 1]

And when using the line:

```
fColor = vec4(1,1,1,1);
```

I get the following correct rendering:

[image: Image 2]

Now, there are other shaders in the system, particularly, I have another shader that also have an attribute by the name of:

```
vTextCoord
```

However, that shader is not linked together with the problematic shader.
I know it is related to the fact another shader that share the attribute name exists on the system (because if I change the name the issue disappears).

Am I doing something terribly wrong?
Did anyone encounter something similar in the past?
Are there known issues with the GLSL compiler that can relate to this?

Comment: The vertex shader misses to set `gl_Position`. But that doesn't really explain the symptoms you're describing.

Comment: The original shader does not miss that, I tried to minimize the test case as much as I could...